# why does my global variable not carry its value between functions

Tags: javascript, global-variables, innerhtml

At the top of my JavaScript document, which is linked to an HTML page, I declared:

```
var pizzaVar;
```

Then, I have a function later in the code that sets the variable's value and then calls another function:

```
function makePizza()
{
    pizzaVar = document.getElementById("pizzaDiv").innerHTML;
    givePizzaToppings();
}
```

But when I tried to use `pizzaVar` in the next function to set the innerHTML of `pizzaDiv`, nothing happened:

```
function givePizzaToppings()
{
    var toppings = "<p>Onions and Bacon</p>";
    pizzaVar = toppings;
}
```

However, if I changed the last line to

```
document.getElementById("pizzaDiv").innerHTML = toppings;
```

it worked. I don't want to have to put that in everytime I want to change `pizzaDiv` though, is there a way to fix this.

PS: I tried saying

```
var pizzaVar= document.getElementById("pizzaDiv").innerHTML;
```

outside of the functions but I got an error message saying:

```
TypeError: null is not an object(evaluating 'document.getElementById("pizzaDiv").innerHTML')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `pizzaVar` will point to a string value, which will be the HTML at the time of the assignment. It doesn't magically setup a link to change it.

If you wanted to use this global variable, you'd be better off pointing it to the `div` element and then using `innerHTML` every time you wanted to change its value.

Then you should research to understand why `innerHTML` is rarely the best tool to modify the DOM.

Comment: Is the JavaScript loaded before the HTML?  If so, change it to load after - otherwise it can't find the elements you're referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, whenever you want to change the `.innerHtml` of your pizza div, you're going to have to write `document.getElementById("pizzaDiv").innerHTML` on the left side of an equals sign. `pizzaVar` is not a pointer, and doesn't point to the `.innerHtml` of the div.

The error you got is telling you that `document.getElementById("pizzaDiv")` returned `null` and hence has no properties at all, much less an `.innerHtml` property. This is because it did not exist at the time of the `.getElementById` call.